# Building Qscintilla2 python bindings on Windows7 with MinGW (PyQt4.11, Qt4.8.6)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, mingw, qscintilla

I've tried to resolve this prolem for about 3days, and I'd finally felt that I need to ask for help by creating my own question.
I have **Windows 7x64** and **Qt4.8.6** installed.
I need **Python** with **PyQt** and **Qscintilla2** to be installed and working.
Now I wil describe my last actions. I did everything like included packages instructions said.
**1)** Installed **Python2.7.9 32bit** from official website.
**2)** Downloaded **SIP** from [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download) (dev snapshot), then:
 `configure.py —platform win32-g++
mingw32-make
mingw32-make install`
**3)** Downloaded **PyQt** from [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/downl..) (not the installer but dev snapshot, cause I need to build with **MinGW** and istaller producec MSVC version), then:
 `configure-ng.py -spec win32-g++
mingw32-make
mingw32-make install`
Ater these steps I tested PyQt on my project - **everything works fine.**
Then I starded trying to install Qsnitilla2.
**4)** Downloaded **Qsnitilla2** from [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/qscintilla..) (dev snapshot), then:
*a) in Qt4Qt5 folder:*
 `qmake qscintilla.pro -spec win32-g++
mingw32-make
mingw32-make install`
This had installed **Qsnitilla2** in **Qt4.8.6** as I saw;
*b) in Python folder( F..ing Python bindngs, excuse my french):*
 `config.py —spec win32-g++
mingw32-make`
after this I got ld.exe error (linking error):
[image: Console screenshot]

Then, afted doing some research, I manually edited my Makefile.Release (by adding **-lpython27** to LIBS parameter):
 `LIBS = -L"c:\Qt-mingw\4.8.6\lib" -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Qt-mingw\4.8.6\lib -lqscintilla2 -lQtGui4 -lQtCore4 -lpython27` 

After this, my `mingw32-make` completed succesfully. So:
 `mingw32-make install` 
This had installed **Qscintilla2** Python bindings.
***Now I can see Qsci autocomlplete in Eclipse.***
So i've tried this:
 `from PyQt4.Qsci import QsciScintilla` 
And i've got this in traceback:
 `from PyQt4.Qsci import QsciScintilla
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль 
(Translation: The specified module could not be found)`

I've tried this with both *dev snapshot* and *src packages* from Riverbank website. And also with **MinGW 4.8.1** and **MinGW-w64 4.8.4**. I can't use *MinGW-w64* over *4.8 version* cause I need *boost-1.55* and it only supports *MinGW 4.8*.
I don't know what to do now, but I really want to use Scintilla in my project. So i'll be very gratefull for any suggestions.

Comment: Why are you trying to compile everything from source, rather than simply installing the [binary packages](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download)?

Comment: I can't do this, because I need all of this (SIP, PyQT4 and Qscintilla) to work with MinGW, and these binary packages provides only MSVC version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever tried to load the QsciScintilla right from the console? I mean you need to enter the directory where the QScintilla located( this means current folder is the default folder), then try run the command "from PyQt4.Qsci import QsciScintilla", if this load module failure still happens, this possibly means you need extra dynamic which QScintilla depends, you need to use [dll dependency](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find out if some other libraries were missing, then put the missing libraries into the same folder of QsciScintilla.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot, really. After 3 days, the resolution was so simple. After using Dependency walker I found that qscintilla2.dll was missing in my Qsci.pyd. Adding path to this .dll in my environment PATH solved the problem.